# Duplicate class error when building Android project in Java. Using Android Studio flamingo 2022.2.1 patch2

Tags: java, xml, class

I'm encountering a lot of errors while trying to build my Android project, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-v4-22.2.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource file D:\PracticaTehnologica2023\MyApplicationCP\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
```

I've already tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, as well as modifying the implementation versions, but the issue persists. As a beginner, I would appreciate any guidance on resolving these errors.
Additionally, I have a question about the relationship between styles.xml and themes.xml files. When I initially created my project, it included themes.xml files, but I added a styles.xml file to define my custom items. I'm unsure if these files are supposed to be separate or if they should be consolidated in some way.

build.gradle (Project: MyApplicationCp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
    dependencies {
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}
```

build.gradle (Module :app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
`your text`
android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplicationcp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplicationcp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'




    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file add some stuff:

```
...
dependencies {
     constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0")
    }
}
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Credit to jbaez

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35979